# Term for a graph with a regular polygon with labeled points and an irregular polygon inside of it

Tags: phrase-requests

Taking a personality quiz on FiveThirtyEight, there were these graphs, consisting of a regular pentagon and an irregular pentagon inside with the points further from the center being lesser and points closer to the edge being greater, on top of regularly spaced bars:

[image: An example of this kind of graph with personality traits]

I've seen this type of graph in other places. For example, on the website for the video game ARMS:

[image: The same kind of graph, but with a hexagon instead]

I was trying to think of a word for this, and couldn't. **What are these called?**

Comment: I would call it an "unpentagon".

Comment: [Radar chart or spider chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In data visualization, it is called a

> [radar or spider chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart)

because it looks like either a radar screen with the values as you go around the circle, or it just sort looks like a spider's web.

It is essentially a bar chart or line chart of a small set on the same scale that, instead of being arranged linearly, is arranged circularly. The spider's web is like the y-axis on a linear chart, and the colored part is the value of each item.

Placing radar charts side by side allows a comparison of many dimensions at once based on comparison of the shapes (a much more accessible comparison than [Chernoff faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_face).  It is similar to Nightingale's famous [rose chart](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/nightingale_rose_chart.html) but the latter implies a cyclical order to the categories whereas a radar chart involves unordered categories.

[FiveThirtyEight has a good use of radar charts to compare candidates.](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-5-key-constituencies-of-the-2020-democratic-primary/) (see the graphic just above 'Group 1').

Answer (score 1):

## Polygon-circle graph

This kind of graph is called a ‘polygon-circle graph’, according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon-circle_graph).

Answer (score 0):

It is just a plot of a point in five-dimensional space. The outer pentagon represents the first orthant in a five-dimensional space, or the convex hull of possible scores to the personality quiz.

Comment: That's what it *is*, but the question asked what it is *called*.

Comment: @nnnnnn. One rarely gets far by sticking to the question.